# MacOS - Using function keys without Fn modifier only in specific apps

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that I can enable the option to have the F-keys function without holding Fn in this options menu:

`Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `Function Keys` > `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`

However this will enable this behavior globally and make it quite annoying if I instead do want to use the shortcut buttons, it basically just flips the issue.

I spend most of my day in an IDE (Jetbrains', not that it matters too much which one it is) and there's lots of shortcuts here where I have to rely on the F-keys, for example looking up function usage is `Option` + `F7`, or looking at problems at my cursor is `Command` + `F1`.

Is there a way for me to have the F-keys behave as regular F-keys only in my IDE, while still enabling me to use the shortcuts for volume, brightness etc. when I'm in any other application without having to hold the `Fn` key for either situation?

Comment: Have you considered just remapping the keys you need to use in Jetbrains (if possible)? Not a perfect solution, but it could do the trick.